# point color based upon column value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to format the color of points based upon the color named in the column. For example, I want point 1 to be red and point 2 to be blue based upon the color named in the column `color`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 2), color = c("red", "blue"))
```

I have tried to plot this `df` using

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes( x = x, y = y, color = color)) + geom_point()
```

and

```
ggplot(df, aes( x = x, y = y, color = color)) + geom_point()
    scale_color_manual(values = unique(df$color))
```

But neither of these produces the outcome I want. How do I change the color of points to be the color named in a dataframe?

I have searched SO (using terms such as *[ggplot2] color column value*), but have not been able to find an answer (if I'm using the wrong terms, please point me in the correct direction).

Comment: See `scale_color_identity()`.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you for sharing and marking as a duplicate. How did you search this site to find the duplicate answer? My SO ninja search skills can also use improving.

Comment: Yeah, it's all about the search terms.  I googled "ggplot2 plot actual colors" and this was the thirdish of the SO posts that came up.